# How to add characters to a variable/integer name - Python

Tags: python, variables, unicode

There might be a question like this but I can't find it.
I want to be to add the name of a variable/integer. e.g.

```
num = 5
chr(0x2075)
```

Now the 2nd line would return 5 in superscript but I want to put the word num into the Unicode instead so something like `chr(0x207+num)` would return 5 in superscript.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: `chr(0x2070 + num)`

Comment: Thank you for that. I didn't know it was that easy!

Answer (score 1):

```
chr(0x2070 + num)
```

As given in the comment, if you want to get the character at U+207x, this is correct.

But this is ***not*** the proper way to find the superscript of a number, because U+2071 is `ⁱ` (superscript "i") while U+2072 and U+2073 are not yet assigned.

```
>>> chr(0x2070 + 1)
'ⁱ'
```

The real superscripts `¹` (U+00B9), `²` (U+00B2), `³` (U+00B3) are out of place.

```
>>> chr(0xb9), chr(0xb2), chr(0xb3)
('¹', '²', '³')
```

Unfortunately, like most things Unicode, the only sane solution here is to hard code it:

```
def superscript_single_digit_number(x):
    return u'⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹'[x]
```